# Have Windows SDK 10586 installed through Visual Studio 2015 for Cordova but Windows reports absence of this SDK

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, sqlite, msbuild, windows-10-universal

I have quite similar problem, like dev who created this question -> [Installed Windows Universal SDK 10586, but Windows still reports it has 10240](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40367287/installed-windows-universal-sdk-10586-but-windows-still-reports-it-has-10240).

I've installed VS 2015 Community for building Cordova app for Windows 10 Mobile.
Have installed Windows SDK v. 14393 and v. 10586, in VS installer this 10586 sdk is even checked as being installed already.

But when I start app's build process, it breaks with info:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Application
>   Type\Windows
>   Store\10.0\Platforms\arm\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(44,5):
>   error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 10.0.10586.0 was not found.
>   Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version
>   in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and
>   selecting "Retarget solution".
>   [C:\Users\some_user\Development\Projects\projects_list\sample1\cordova\plugins\c
>   ordova-sqlite-storage\src\windows\SQLite3-Win-RT\SQLite3\SQLite3.UWP\SQLite3.UWP.vcxproj]
>   Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe: Command
>   failed with exit code 1

When I'm trying to install this SDK manually, from installer sdksetup.exe with SDK in version 10.0.10586.212. alert window appears with text:

> You must uninstall the Windows Software Development Kit - Windows
>   10.0.10586.212 before you can install the latest version of the kit.

Reinstalling VS didn't helped, also I've tried with completely uninstalling VS, deleting every single one entry in windows registry that had IMO something to do with 10.0.10586.0 and 10.0.10586.212 SDK's, then use CCleaner to cleanup and install VS again.
Still nothing.

Is it possible, that required version of SDK wasn't configured correctly during installation?

I had earlier installed both VS 2015 and VS 2017 and building, debugging and deploying Cordova app for Windows 10 worked like a charm, but I decided to use only one IDE, deleted 2017 and building apps still worked, then decided to make clean install of VS 2015 and after that, build process got screwed.

Cheers for eventual help.

Comment: Build 10586/V1511 support ends in september 2017, so target your solution to at least Build 14393

Comment: The case is, I'm not editing the targeting of Cordova Windows platform.
I just set in config.xml for Cordova platforms, that Windows versions of app should use spec="5.0.0" version of platform and it must be built for Windows 10 Mobile.
Also, the whole problem is with the 10586 sdk version which I can't install and don't know why...

Comment: Have you tried to repair the SDK installation or just try to install a different version?

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/develop/building-a-driver

> > The TargetPlatformVersion setting is optional and allows you to specify the kit version to build with. The default is to use the latest kit.<<
> >     10.0.15063.0

With kind regards